# Difference between conditional expectation E(Y|X) and E(Y|X=x)

Tags: statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

I'm trying to solve this problem and have a few questions.

[image]

So for part i), I don't know how to find this conditional expectation without pure intuition that it seems to be $\frac{3+x}{2}$

part ii) I'm conceptually confused by this because the right-hand side is just X instead of "X=x" (so just a general X versus a specific number). How would I calculate this?

part iii) I'd need to know how to do part i and ii to describe this

part iv) I could just use the law of iterated expectations here, where E(Y) = E[E(Y|X)]. Pretty straightforward.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\operatorname E(Y\mid X=x) = \frac{x+3} 2.
$$
Since $x$ is not a random variable, neither is $\dfrac{x+3} 2.$

But $\operatorname E(Y\mid X) = \dfrac{X+3} 2$ is a random variable, since $X$ is a random variable.

Comment: wow that's actually a really cool distinction! 

And any way to get an actual calculation method for the (x+3)/2? It honestly just came to me through trial-and-error but I'd like to be able to not have to resort to that

Comment: A random variable that is uniformly distributed on the interval $[a,b]$ has expected value $(a+b)/2.$ The thing that is "uniform" is the density, i.e. the density is constant on the interval. If that constant is called $c$ then we have $\displaystyle \int_a^b c\, dx =1.$ But $\displaystyle\int_a^b c\,dx = c(b-a),$ so we must have $c=1/(b-a).$ The expected value is then $$ \int_a^b xf(x)\,dx = \int_a^b x \cdot \frac1 {b-a} \,dx = \frac{a+b}2. $$ That is where $(x+3)/2$ came from. $\qquad$

Comment: ah true true true. Thanks!